# How to use alias in laravel eager loading

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4, eager-loading

I want to use  alias with laravel eager loading. This is my query

```php
Message::whereIn('conversation_id',$msgs)
        ->where('deleted', '!=', $userId)
        ->with(array('last_sender' =>function($query) use ($userId){
                $query->where('id','!=', $userId);
                $query->select('id', 'userName', 'profilePic','firstName', 'lastName');
          }))

         ->with(array('last_reciever' =>function($query) use ($userId){
                $query->where('id','!=', $userId);
                $query->select('id', 'userName', 'profilePic','firstName', 'lastName');
          }))
         ->orderBy('conversation_id', 'desc') 
         ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
         ->groupBy('conversation_id')
        ->get();
```

This query returns user object either as `last_sender` and `last_reciever` stays null or `last_reciever` and `last_sender` stays null. 
This is the result object that this query returns

```php
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 85,
        "conversation_id": 18,
        "last_reciever": null,
        "last_sender": {
            "id": 39,
            "userName": "df76236sd",
            "profilePic": "aFHZmeMHQ6nd3Ll3nzCqYEw2CTBsun3f1hxm3yKc.jpeg",
            "firstName": "sadek ",
            "lastName": "sdfsd"
        },
        "msg": "abe sala",
        "attachment": null,
        "deleted": 0,
        "seen": 0,
        "created_at": "2017-08-19 02:24:05",
        "updated_at": "2017-08-19 02:24:05"
    },
    {
        "id": 80,
        "conversation_id": 16,
        "last_reciever": {
            "id": 39,
            "userName": "df76236sd",
            "profilePic": "aFHZmeMHQ6nd3Ll3nzCqYEw2CTBsun3f1hxm3yKc.jpeg",
            "firstName": "sadek ",
            "lastName": "sdfsd"
        },
        "last_sender": null,
        "msg": "now should be working just fine",
        "attachment": null,
        "deleted": 0,
        "seen": 1,
        "created_at": "2017-08-19 02:19:34",
        "updated_at": "2017-08-19 02:19:34"
     }
   ]
  }
```

What I am trying to do is replace the both `last_sender` and `last_reciever` with a custom name `oponent` . For this I tried to use something like this

```php
Message::whereIn('conversation_id',$msgs)
        ->where('deleted', '!=', $userId)
        ->with(array('last_sender as oponent' =>function($query) use ($userId){
                $query->where('id','!=', $userId);
                $query->select('id', 'userName', 'profilePic','firstName', 'lastName');
          }))

         ->with(array('last_reciever as oponent' =>function($query) use ($userId){
                $query->where('id','!=', $userId);
                $query->select('id', 'userName', 'profilePic','firstName', 'lastName');
          }))
         ->orderBy('conversation_id', 'desc') 
         ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
         ->groupBy('conversation_id')
        ->get();
```

And it doesn't work. Is there any other ways to achieve this? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could either override the values in the model using toArray()

```
    public function toArray()
    {
        return [
           'oponent' => $this->last_sender. " " .$this->last_reciever,
        ];
    }
```

Or use laravel api resources

```
    class User extends JsonResource
{
    /**
    * Transform the resource into an array.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
    * @return array
    */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
           'id' => $this->id,
           'name' => $this->name,
           'email' => $this->email,
           'created_at' => $this->created_at,
           'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
       ];
    }
}
```

If you want to return a collection using laravel api resources

```
Route::get('/user', function () {
    return UserResource::collection(User::all());
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources